# renaming txt files

Tags: rename

I have a list of files named like this

```
SLX-11025.N701_N504.C8912ANXX.txt
```

And need to rename them based on this small part `N701_N504`, and each will be renamed to an specific code (for example - `N701_N504` will be case `400-001`,  `N701_N505` be case `400-002`, etc).

Comment: You should show an attempt to script this and then if you get stuck, show why.

Comment: The question could use some clarification, too. How does `N701_N504` map onto `400-001` — subtraction, a table, what? Do you want to keep the other parts of the name? Show some examples with the full input and output filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is a separate folder --

```
for i in SLX*; do val=$(echo $i | grep -oE "50."); val=$((val-504+1)); new=$(printf "400-%03d" $val); mv $i $new; done
```